# Python multiprocessing TypeError: join() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)

Tags: python, multithreading, multiprocessing, terminate

I've made a lot of studying about multiprocessing!
Basically I'm downloading data from an API and insert in a database.

I made a pool and access the function of download with a pool.imap, make a tuple with the results and insert all in one shot in DB.

I access this function repeatedly and at some point in time my process got hang!
I've tried to follow https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.multiprocessing.Pool.map and access the join with timeout.

But pool.join(timeout) returns "TypeError: join() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)". I suppose that the one argument is the default "self"?

A short chunk of the code:

```
timeout = 10
pool = Pool(10)
in_tuple = [x for x in pool.imap(multi_details,items) if x is not None]
pool.close()
pool.join(timeout) # from the documentation I should be able to put the timeout in join

writing_to_database(in_tuple)

# function that generate the content for DB
def multi_details(item):
        tuple = get_details(item)
        return tuple
```

I see different way to create processes and generate terminate() or join(timeout) but neither one is using imap/map - which are a much simpler to work in my case!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the solution!

I didn't manage to use "next(timeout)" because it just parse a few items than stops before running entire list!

I start to use **apply_async**. The only thing is that I have a strange feeling that it is slower than **imap**.

The functional code is:

```
timeout = 1
pool = Pool(10)
for x in items:
    try:
        res = pool.apply_async(multi_details,(x,)).get(timeout)
    except Exception as e:
        pass # you can put anything you want but my scope was to skip the things that took too much!
    else:
        if res is not None: # now this could be a better pythonic way to write this. Any help will be highly appreciated!
            in_tuple.append(res)
pool.close()
pool.join()
```

Thank you and I hope it's useful!

Answer (score 1):

Unlike the `Process` class the `Pool` class does not accept a `timeout` parameter in its `join` method : 
https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.multiprocessing.Pool.join

Comment: Oh damn it, so there is no way to pass the multiprocess function if one of the workers hung up? :(

Comment: You can add a timeout argument in the `imap` method according to the doc https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.multiprocessing.Pool.imap

Comment: I'll try to change `x for x in pool.imap(multi_details,items) if x is not None` with   `for x in pool.imap(multi_details,items): 
        if x.next(1) is not None:  
            in_tuple.append(x)`   . If it works I believe will be useful for a lot of  
 people!

Comment: I've tried the "next" method but I only get 8 responses. `results = pool.imap(multi_details,items)
    for result in results.next():
        print result` My pool class definition Pool(10) . I even tried to make a different process `monitor = multiprocessing.Process(name='monitor',target=timeout,args=(pool,))` where the pool arg is the Pool object. And inside it "pool.terminate()", but no effect!